# Cannot open Azure Machine Learning Workbench

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Trying to set up the workbench after the MS Ignite presentation. I have a free account tied to my ancient hotmail but it says

"No experimentation account found in your Azure subscriptions"

Comment: Can you clarify what your free account is? As mentioned below, you need an account that is tied to an azure subscription.

Comment: Been a while since I did it. I had credit from my last employer's MSDN subscription. And I don't remember all the details but after I installed the ML workbench I had to link it to a specific Azure resource that gave me some free access. Sorry, I did this only once then switched jobs and don't remember all the details of what I had to do. I do remember it took me a day of messing with it.

Answer (score 4):

Azure ML Workbench is tied to the new Experimentation account and not the traditional Azure ML workspace account used by ML Studio. Workbench requires an Azure subscription with an Experimentation account setup first. The first two Experimentation seats are free.

To setup Workbench, follow the order outlined in the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/quickstart-installation

Workbench showing Experimentation account logged in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEgiD.png